# Multiple post types for BuddyBlog plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, buddypress

Hello can anybody help me to return  "multiple" Custom Post Types in this snippet? I would like to use 3-5 other custom post types and I can't get it work.

The snippet above for ONE custom post type works, the snippet below for multiple custom post types doesn't.

```
add_filter( 'buddyblog_get_post_type', 'buddyblog_my_post_type' );
function buddyblog_my_post_type( $post_type ) {
    return 'portfolio';
}
```

I have tried this and several other snippets without a success:

```
add_filter( 'buddyblog_get_post_type', 'buddyblog_my_post_type' );
function buddyblog_my_post_type( $array ) {
    $array = array( 'post','portfolio' );
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't.

Having had a quick look through the [BuddyBlog code](http://buddydev.com/plugins/buddyblog/), everything expects the filter to return a single post type.

My only suggestion is to [contact the author](http://buddydev.com/members/sbrajesh/) & request support for multiple post types, or take it upon yourself to make the adjustments (the joys of open source!).

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP at all, so even I am not happy with this fact I gave you vote up for your quick and clear answer,  I will contact Brajesh for multiple post types support. Thanks